# How do I explore the source of a gem that isn't installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I just have the gem on my desktop. How can I inspect it's source in Sublime Text or Xcode or anything really? I know I can check installed gems out with Sublime Text, what about uninstalled ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gem unpack foo.gem` then just go into the foo/ directory

see http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_unpack

Comment: Don't you love it when things are so simple? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the `gem` tool either (unlikely, but just in case), a gem is a `tar` archive with several `gz` and `tar.gz` files in it, so you can get the contents using the standard `tar` and `gzip` utilities.